# How to automatically refresh open files after changes by a pre-build event

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, pre-build-event, delphi-ide

In Delphi XE3 I have a pre-build event that generates .pas files. The generated files are in the project's search path and this works fine.

When one of those files is currently opened in the Delphi editor, the pre-build event will still run fine and update the .pas file. The problem is just, that the Delphi-IDE does not notice that this file has changed. i.e. when I just switch to another program and then back to the Delphi-IDE the change will be recognized - and I will be asked if I want to update the file in the editor.

Is there a way to force this behavior in my pre-build event command?

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to do this easily. The IDE checks when it is activated. If I were you I'd stop trying to force the ide to fit your design, and make the design fit in with the ide.

Comment: You could write an IDE expert but I think that's a waste of time.  Working this way seems fundamentally insane.

Comment: Well, then please enlighten me: what is the Delph way or design of generating source files?